# Is there any difference between `flatMap` and `block` in case of "nested" `Mono`

Tags: project-reactor

As I understand both `flatMap` and `block` ends with `subscribe`, so is there any difference in below statements?

```
Mono.just("a").flatMap(value -> Mono.just("b")).subscribe();
```

```
Mono.just("a").doOnNext(value -> Mono.just("b").block()).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, they are very different. The second one blocks the main thread. The following code is going to block the main thread for 5 seconds:

```java
@Test
void test_blockingCode() {
    Mono.just("a")
         .doOnNext(value -> Mono.just("b").delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).block())
         .subscribe();
    }
```

Here is the thread dump:

> "main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1550,32ms elapsed=4,41s
> tid=0x00007f376002c4e0 nid=0x2060 waiting on condition
> [0x00007f3768ae3000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)     at
> jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.$$BlockHound$$_park(java.base@16.0.2/Native
> Method)
>
> - parking to wait for  <0x0000000611d97458> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)    at
>   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@16.0.2/Unsafe.java)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@16.0.2/LockSupport.java:211)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(java.base@16.0.2/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:714)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(java.base@16.0.2/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1046)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(java.base@16.0.2/CountDownLatch.java:232)
>   at
>   reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87)
>   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1704)